# why is my php command not working after I hosted it?

Tags: php, html, sql, web, host

I hosted my website and then suddenly the php command for inserting a record into the database doesn't work.

Here is the code of the command, the success message works but the record isn't inserted in the database. When I run the website locally, it works fine. Some of the commands of my website are working in terms of being able to insert into the database, but some are just like this problem, the success message is working but the database doesn't change

```
function doInsert(){
    global $mydb;
    if(isset($_POST['save'])){


    if ($_POST['U_NAME'] == "" OR $_POST['U_USERNAME'] == "" OR $_POST['U_PASS'] == "") {
        $messageStats = false;
        message("All field is required!","error");
        redirect('index.php?view=add');
    }else{  

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM useraccounts WHERE ACCOUNT_USERNAME='" .$_POST['U_USERNAME']."'";
        $mydb->setQuery($sql);
        $userresult = $mydb->loadSingleResult(); 
        if ($userresult) {
            # code...
            message("Username is already taken.", "error");
            redirect('index.php?view=add');
        }else{

        $user = New User();
        $user->USERID               = $_POST['user_id'];
        $user->ACCOUNT_NAME         = $_POST['U_NAME'];
        $user->ACCOUNT_USERNAME     = $_POST['U_USERNAME'];
        $user->ACCOUNT_PASSWORD     =sha1($_POST['U_PASS']);

        $user->ACCOUNT_TYPE         =  $_POST['U_ROLE'];
        $user->create();

        message("New [". $_POST['U_NAME'] ."] created successfully!", "success");
        redirect("index.php");

        } 
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection, you do no sanity checks that POST variables are present and you use `sha1` to hash the password rather than `password_hash`. The above code though does not attempt to INSERT data - unless that is done by the `$user->create()` method which you have not shown

Comment: you need to do some more detailed debugging, ensure you've got error logging enabled, and check for exceptions and warnings. With the info you've given, we can only guess what the problem might be. And yes you need to urgently fix your SQL injection vulnerability and start using parameterised queries to put user data into your SQL strings.